# Why is the bottom half of my 35mm photos black?

Tags: 35mm

So this isn’t in all my photos only some, I    Use a Pentax super A1. The bottom half of the photo sometimes comes out as nothing. This is annoying and unpredictable. I have read that  It may be the shutter, so would using it at a slower shutter speed maybe help? I usually adjust apature manually and let the camera decide the shutter speed. Could I maybe not go [image]quicker than 250? I just cant remember which shuttter speed the photos that came out okay were taken at/#.

Comment: Are you using flash?

Comment: Not using a flash, and its not all photos effected.

Comment: Just because all photos are not affected does not mean your shutter is not malfunctioning. Shutters typically start with isolated random events and get progressively worse until total failure.

Comment: As with most of these types of questions, the answer is always pretty much "get it serviced". These sorts of models have lots of moving mechanical parts, and even if they still work they need to be serviced regularly.

Answer (score 5):

The example photo appears to be the result of a malfunctioning shutter mechanism. It most likely need to be replaced. If your camera is not worth what a shutter replacement would cost, then it's time to consider a new (or different used) camera.